# Understand Cassandra pooling options (setCoreConnectionsPerHost and setMaxConnectionsPerHost)?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I recently started working with Cassandra and I was reading more about connection pooling [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/pooling/). I was confuse about pool size and couldn't understand what does this mean here:

```
poolingOptions
    .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL,  4)
    .setMaxConnectionsPerHost( HostDistance.LOCAL, 10)
    .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2)
    .setMaxConnectionsPerHost( HostDistance.REMOTE, 4)
    .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(2000);
```

Below is what I want to understand in detail:

1. I would like to know what does `setCoreConnectionsPerHost`, `setMaxConnectionsPerHost` and `setMaxRequestsPerConnection` means?
2. What is `LOCAL` and `REMOTE` means here?

If someone can explain with an example then it will really help me understand better.

We have a 6 nodes cluster all in one dc with RF as 3 and we read/write as local quorum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cassandra protocol allows to submit for execution multiple queries over the same network connection in parallel, without waiting for answer.  The `setMaxRequestsPerConnection` sets how many in-flight queries could be in one connection simultaneously - maximal limit depends on protocol, and since protocol v3, it's 32k, but in reality you need to keep it around 1000-2000 - if you have more, then it's a sign that server is not keeping with your queries.

Drivers are opening connections to every node in the cluster, and these connections are marked either as `LOCAL` - if they are to the nodes in the data center that is local to the application (either set explicitly in load balancing policy, or inferred from first contacted point), or as `REMOTE` if they are to the nodes that in the other data centers.

Also, driver can open several connections to nodes. And there are 2 values that control their number: `core` - the minimal number of connections, and `max` - what is the upper limit.  Driver will open new connections if you submit new requests that doesn't fit into the existing limit.

So in your example:

```java
poolingOptions
    .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL,  4)
    .setMaxConnectionsPerHost( HostDistance.LOCAL, 10)
    .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2)
    .setMaxConnectionsPerHost( HostDistance.REMOTE, 4)
    .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(2000);
```

- for local data center, it will open 4 connections per node initially, and it may grow up to 10 connections
- for other data centers it will open 2 connections, that could grow up to 4 connections

Comment: hey, do you know how can we do `setMaxRequestsPerConnection` explicitly in cassandra go driver? I haven't been able to find it so far.

Comment: it's better to ask it as explicit question

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75567084/how-to-set-pool-size-in-gocql