# How many parallel write requests can a single Node.js driver connection process?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-node-driver

How many parallel write requests can I make to cassandra from a single connection in a nodejs process?

I am using:
cassandra-driver@4.6.3 : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cassandra-driver
I am not using batch... as i understand it is not recommended if all data is not in same partition.

My main concern is limitation if any from cassandra connection point of view..

From: [Understand Cassandra pooling options (setCoreConnectionsPerHost and setMaxConnectionsPerHost)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62144579/understand-cassandra-pooling-options-setcoreconnectionsperhost-and-setmaxconnec)
I understand that 32k parallel write is approx limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32k is the theoretical upper limit on the number of queries in-flight, but the real number heavily depends on the size of the cluster, how load is spread between nodes, etc. Sometimes, having more in-flight requests will put an additional load onto the cluster, and your latencies will be heavily increasing.

As I mentioned in that answer, it's recommended to test your setup & find optimal number of requests per connection.  You can use [NoSQLBench tool](https://github.com/nosqlbench/nosqlbench) to find optimal configurations.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for quick revert, also in related matter, this issue has cm up bcse we are trying to avoid batching [since write is across partitions].
So hence one batch now splits into 500 individual writes.

I understand if we want to use batching [across partitions] we should benchmark it right before using such an approach?

Comment: basically one batch with 500 rows vs 10 batch requests with 50 rows each vs 500 individual writes..

Comment: if you can combine writes into the same partition into a batch, then it would be big improvement as it will be one write operation. if it's not possible, then do 500 individual writes - just make sure that you're using prepared statements with token aware load balancing policy (default one)

Answer (score 0):

For the Node.js driver, the maximum requests per connection for native protocol v3 or newer is `2048` by default (for older native protocols v1 and v2 it's just `128`).

It's not 32K as you quoted. The other post you linked isn't relevant to your question since it applies to the Cassandra Java driver.

For details, see [Connection pooling with the Node.js driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.6/features/connection-pooling/#simultaneous-requests-per-connection). Cheers!