# How do I set the maximum pool size in gocql?

Tags: go, cassandra, gocql

I wanted to know how can we explicitly set max pool size in `gocql`?

I mean changing the number of queries which will be run simultaneously.

We are having `200ms` avg response time in Grafana, but we are seeing `24ms` avg read latency in Cassansra exporter panels. Can it be related to pool size?

P.S. I think that's the function in Java driver: `poolingOptions.setMaxRequestsPerConnection(num)`. What is the equivalent function in gocql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an equivalent of the Cassandra Java driver's `setMaxRequestsPerConnection()` in gocql.

The gocql default is 2 connections per host ([`NumConns: 2` in `cluster.go`](https://github.com/gocql/gocql/blob/7a6cf00bbc98f4d7037e4a0fcca96fc946fd63d6/cluster.go#L250)) and on the server-side, Cassandra will accept up to 128 concurrent requests ([`native_transport_max_threads: 128` in `cassandra.yaml`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0/conf/cassandra.yaml#L709-L711)). Cheers!

Comment: NumConns is actually the number connection to db. The requests will be sent through these connections simultaneously. So I think increasing the number of connections would do the job, thanks.

Comment: I am also using the default setting NumConns:2. Latencies are a little higher, I have 8 nodes per datacenter 2 datacenters, CL is LOCAL_QUORUM and cluster RF is 3. Also application cluster has 8 nodes, so 16 connections to each Cassandra node? Is it correct?